# Trying to populate dynamic form fields with Ajax database call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I just about have this working but am stuck on the final bit. I have a dynamic html form that the user can click on a link to add additional fields below the existing parent field. These dynamic fields include a  list which is pre-populated with DB entries. Next to the select are two empty text inputs that I populate with another ajax DB call once the user has selected an item from the  list.

I can get this working when there is just a single additional dynamic form field added, but when there is more than one, selecting an entry from the  field will only alter the text values of the first dynamic field.

This is the code that populates the  field and builds the other html table and input elements that the user can add:

```
$php_var = htmlspecialchars($_GET['js_var']);

$sql = "call list_ad_locations_grouped('$php_var');";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Query fail: " . 
mysqli_error($conn));
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$conn->next_result();

echo "<table border=\"0\" style=\"width: 100%; cellpadding: 0px; 
cellspacing: 1px;\" ><tr><td style=\"width: 30%; height: 30px;\">\n";
echo "<select name=\"newlocation[]\" id=\"newlocation\" style=\"width: 
218px\" onChange=\"showUser(this.value)\">\n";
echo "<option value=\"0\">Select...</option>\n";
while ($rowz = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo "<option value=\"". $rowz['locationID'] ."\">". $rowz['description'] ." 
</option>\n";
}
echo "<select></td>\n";

echo "<td style=\"width: 20%\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"available[]\" 
id=\"avail\" size=\"2\"></td>\n";
echo "<td style=\"width: 22%\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"cost[]\" 
id=\"cost\" size=\"7\" value=\" \"></td>\n";
echo "<td style=\"width: 10%\"></td>\n";
echo "<td><div align=\"left\" style=\"padding-left: 4px\"><a href=\"#\" 
title=\"Delete this location?\" onclick=\"delLocation()\"><img 
src=\"img/delete.png\" border=\"0\"></a></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";
```

[image: Dynamic select field]

When selecting an item from the select list, the onChange event fires an Ajax call to another php page to make the DB query to look up the values to populate the remaining inputs. This works well with just one field added using this code:

```
 function showFields(str)
  {
   if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("available").value="";
  return;
  }
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) 
    {

       document.getElementById("avail").value = data[i].theavail;
       document.getElementById("cost").value = data[i].theCost;
    }
  }
 }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","locationprocess2.php?l_var="+str,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

This is the php page the takes the Ajax call:

```
if (isset($_GET['l_var'])){
$locID = htmlspecialchars($_GET['l_var']);

$query = "Select `cost`, `available` From locations Where `locationID` = 
'$locID'";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Query failed: " . 
 mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
$thecost = $row['cost'];
$theavail = $row['available'];
$info[] = array( 'theCost' => $thecost, 'theavail' => $theavail );

}
echo json_encode($info);

}

else 
{
exit;
}
```

It needs to loop through all instances of the form elements with the same ID's, but I am not sure how to accomplish that in the JS code that receives the JSON output.
Many thanks!